# Calling MIPS from C: aligning not-aligned arguments

Tags: c, mips, mips32

I'm calling some functions from C that are code in MIPS.
Sometimes the arguments I pass through $a0 to $a3 are not aligned and throw an error if I try to load them using **lw**.

Is there anyway I can load these not-aligned arguments and convert them to aligned (other than using **lb** and then glue them together)? I don't need to write them back, just read them.

I tried also using "align" in the MIPS code but it didn't work, probably is not meant for that.

EDIT: I'm using GCC 7.4.0

EDIT: I'm using packed structures which contain unaligned data.

Comment: Can you turn off unaligned access faults?

Comment: I'm using GCC 7.4.0, the only info I can find about that is the flag "-mno-unaligned-access" but it is not recognized at least on that version

Comment: Are you using packed structures or do you cast pointers to a type that requires a stricter alignment, e.g. from `uint8_t*`to `uint32_t*`? Your C compiler may know that the variable is unaligned and generate the code with single-byte access, but the assembler code does not automatically do this. Maybe you can call your assembler code from a wrapper function in C that copies the value to an aligned variable before passing it to the assembler code.

Comment: Without code, this question is impossible to answer and will only produce guesswork.

Comment: Thanks Bodo! I'm using packed structures. Creating a wrapper and then creating local variables and passing those through works. It is a system with very limited resources I was hoping there was a faster way of doing that on MIPS but if nothing else comes up I will stick with the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

When you use packed structures in C code, your compiler knows which fields are unaligned and creates the necessary code to access unaligned data. Probably it will do exactly what you describe in the question, i.e. use `lb` instead of `lw` and combine the bytes.

(There are some pitfalls. You can create code where the information of unaligned data can get lost.)

Unfortunately in assembler code you would have to do this manually.

As a workaround you can call your assembler code from a wrapper function in C that copies the value to an aligned variable before passing it to the assembler code.